# Where did my silver gone

Tags: support, badges

:)) Actually title is all I can say

I've got some liver for coming here everyday for 30 days.
I was happy that day I remember and now it's gone with my happiness

Comment: Are you talking about the [Enthusiast badge](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/badges/22/enthusiast)? You need 30 **consecutive** days for that.

Comment: whoooops sorry, It was stackexchange not wordpress one >.<

Yes it was/is Enthusiast one ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You silver badge hasn't gone anywhere, you can see it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1655199/mpa4hu?tab=badges

Note the stackoverflow URL, this is not stackoverflow. You got a silver badge on SO, for visiting SO for 30 days consecutively. Not WordPress Stack Exchange. You're going to have to repeat if you want the badge here too

Answer (score 5):

According to your profile, you've only been a member for 27 days. And you've only visited for 3 consecutive days on Meta (5 consecutive days on WordPress Answers).

Once you build up 30 consecutive days, you'll earn a badge.

Answer (score 3):

#### Silver left a message:

### *I'll go for a ride, be back soon*

[image: hi-yo silver]

Comment: :DDDD Will wait with patience